# Saving image from API Endpoint with no filetype, in python

Tags: python, image, api, spotify

I'm trying to save images from the Spotify API

I get album art in the form of a link:

`https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851c96f7c7b077c224975b4c5ce`

I think it's a jpg file.

I run into errors in trying to display or save this in python.

I'm not even sure how I'm meant to format something like:

Do I need str around the link?
`str(https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851c96f7c7b077c224975b4c5ce)`

Or should I create a new variable e.g.

`image_path = 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851c96f7c7b077c224975b4c5ce'`

And then:

`im1 = im1.save(image_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second suggestion should work with an addition of actually downloading the image using `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request

image_path = 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851c96f7c7b077c224975b4c5ce'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_path, "image.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I was a little confused about that, and also about what code to use to exact the value from the JSON.